# Defining a bit, but without a name?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, embedded

So I have some code for the iodefine of my board. I see a lot of these in structs. What exactly is it doing? Is it just a placeholder for the last 4 bits? Why doesn't it cause a compiler error and what is it used for?

```
union {
    unsigned char BYTE;
    struct {
        unsigned char OVRF:1;
        unsigned char IDLNF:1;
        unsigned char MODF:1;
        unsigned char PERF:1;
        unsigned char :4;        <------------
    } BIT;
} SPSR;
```

I hope thats not too many questions, I just found this very interesting.

Comment: Seems like unnamed padding.

Comment: Instead of `4` you should have `CHAR_BIT - 4` ...

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree with you 100%, but its an auto generated file at about 23k lines so there's not much I can do =P. Thanks for all the answers guys.

Comment: Since it's unionised with a complete unsigned char, I guess it's not really necessary, but for clarity...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Given that this code is narrowly tailored to a very specific piece of hardware containing a Serial Peripheral Status Register with an overrun flag, an idle flag, a mode fault flag, and a parity error flag, using `CHAR_BIT-4` will not accomplish anything. The program is not portable and will never be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an unnamed bit-field. It is used to provide padding (usually between adjacent bit-fields).

> (C99, 6.7.2.1p11) "A bit-field declaration with no declarator, but only a colon and a width, indicates an unnamed bit-field"

Answer (score 2):

```
struct-declarator:
declarator
type-specifier declarator (opt) : constant-expression
```

The declarator is optional, that's why the compiler doesn't barf.